# Show a notification when a title's final dots get removed

Tags: feature-request, title

I tried adding dots to the title of a new question, like so:

> Handling common code between different activities, fragments, tasks, ...

I came back some ten minutes later and noticed the dots were gone! I tried to edit them in, which failed. Then I did:

> Handling common code between different activities, fragments, tasks, etc.

Even that single dot was too much (sob sob) but I can live with it now.

**Is this a recent change?** Why was it added? **Would it be possible to show a popup message just to *tell* someone that his dots have been removed so that he may change his title if he wants?**

My title now looked like:

> Handling common code between different activities, fragments, tasks,

Which is a bit strange. I would have appreciated a notification, so that I could have edited it directly.

Comment: Why do you want to add dots to end of a title?

Comment: @ChrisF I'm okay with it not being possible (and can see reasons why this is not possible), I just would have appreciated the notification. But see my question for an example of why I would try to do this.

Comment: @ChrisF Titles may end in abbreviations suffixed with dots, e.g., _etc._